# Combine permutations with group limitation & lookup values that match these

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations

I have a table like this
[image]
I want to make all Possible combinations of `GROUP` (but I want the `LOAD Case` Value)
but ***a group can't exist twice*** within the same combination
so for example I can't do
`T + TL + W + Wx`
but I can do `T + TL + W` or `T + TL + Wx`

after getting the combination I want to add the `V, Hy, Hx, My, Mx` Values of the combination
each in its corresponding column
so for `T & Tl` for column `V` it would be `3+8` = `11`
I have a larger workbook with around possibly 900 combinations, and I did what u see below with hand, there's possibly some miscalculation but it's just to demonstrate what I need.
I also want the cell value to be dynamic so if I change any value in the `V, Hy, Hx, My, Mx`  columns in the orange table, it will be reflected in the gray table

Comment: You've tagged the question with VBA so please post the code you've tried, where are you stuck and what errors are you getting

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Sorry, I removed the tag, I tried a couple of VBA codes but they're truly far away from achieving what i want. I was just hoping there's someone who face the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, this was 2 questions in one really, but I figured it out:

part 1 was the possible combinations of single load case to a combination of load cases where the load cases listed in a similar group may not be combined with each other. This was the hardest part and I needed a few lambdas to get there:

Improved solution:

```
=LET(a,   A3:A6,
     b,   B3:B6,
     u,   TOROW(UNIQUE(a)),
     pa, REDUCE(TOCOL(u),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(u)-1,,COUNTA(u)-1,-1),
          LAMBDA(c,d,
                 VSTACK(c,
                        REDUCE(TOCOL(u),DROP(u,,d),
                        LAMBDA(e,f,
                               TOCOL(IFS(ISERR(FIND(u,e)),e&";"&u),3)))))),
     pas, SORT(DROP(REDUCE("",pa,LAMBDA(g,h,IFERROR(VSTACK(g,TEXTSPLIT(h,";")),""))),1)),
     pb,  DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(pas)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,REDUCE("",INDEX(pas,y,),LAMBDA(v,w,TOCOL(v&";"&TOROW(FILTER(b,a=w,"")),3)))))),1),
SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(pb,";"," "))," "," & "))
```

This version does not require another lambda at the end, which - if data increases (like in your sample file in the comments) - will completely freeze excel.

old version:

```
=LET(a,   A3:A6,
     b,   B3:B6,
     u,   TOROW(UNIQUE(a)),
     pa,  REDUCE(TOCOL(u),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(u)-1,,COUNTA(u)-1,-1),
          LAMBDA(c,d,
                 VSTACK(c,
                        REDUCE(TOCOL(u),DROP(u,,d),
                        LAMBDA(e,f,
                               TOCOL(IFS(ISERR(FIND(u,e)),e&";"&u),3)))))),
     pas, SORT(DROP(REDUCE("",pa,LAMBDA(g,h,IFERROR(VSTACK(g,TEXTSPLIT(h,";")),""))),1)),
     pb,  DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(pas)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,REDUCE("",INDEX(pas,y,),LAMBDA(v,w,TOCOL(v&";"&TOROW(FILTER(b,a=w,"")),3)))))),1),
BYROW(DROP(REDUCE("",pb,
           LAMBDA(x, y,
                  VSTACK(x,
                         TEXTSPLIT(y,";")))),1,1),
      LAMBDA(x,
TEXTJOIN(" & ",,x))))
```

Basically it first creates the possible permutations of single (unique) groups to the combination of these unique groups adding a different group one at a time.

Part 2 was the need to translate these group-permutations into it's load case-equivalent and if there's more equivalents, add these as another permutation as well.

[image]

Then to sum the `V, Hy, Hx, My, Mx`-values to the corresponding load cases in this spill range, I used the following:

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A8#),COLUMNS(D3:H6),
    LAMBDA(r,        c,
SUM(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A8#,r),," & "),
            B3:B6,
            INDEX(D3:H6,,c)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. More like a dozen of questions.

Comment: Yeah, the first part was hard to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works but if there're other similar groups it will just return 0 when creating possible permutations. Is it a quick fix? If not I'm satisfied with this answer and will mark it as solution, thank you again, really you're amazing.

for example 
A
B
C
C
D
D
E
E
F
F

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but with permutations, you easily reach the calculation limits of Excel, if there's more combinations than rows in excel it will not be able to calculate. Can you share an example of data where it does not work?

Comment: sure, Here's a sample Excel file and you can see the function will return 0
@P.b

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11MH6mwpjXwkHKW16_QCUNuleGqEkxj6g/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=101357463341695247442&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Hmm, i need to share email to request access, not something I prefer. With the ABCCDDEEFF example in your post it takes over 10 minutes to calculate up until it has it's result it will return 0

Comment: With my laptop and given number of variants /groups it calculates in approximately 11 minutes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kbz3.png until calculated it will show `0`.

Comment: maybe you can open a new question to tag vba and focus on the permutation part, instead of the summing. I'm sure using vba can result in a more efficient solution.

Comment: @P.b sorry I forgot to allow the access to the file, you can view it now. However I didn't know it takes time to compute the results, when it returned 0 I thought there's something wrong, and time doesn't matter to me so I don't really need a VBA script. I will try again and wait until it finishes computing. Thank you for your answer again!

Comment: The more data, it will take more time exponentially.

Comment: See updated answer, this does not freeze your excel even with your example file.
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPC9y7BXNpr82G9WDoK?e=rMNRK6

Comment: Still takes over a minute to calculate your sample file on my laptop, but that's way better than 10 minutes for less data.

Comment: Thanks for the challenge. I liked getting that permutations right